# Ipv6 support in Afnetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, ipv6

I am using AFNetworking 3.0 in my iOS application. I am getting response while calling APIs on IPv4 but on IPv6 all my request gets timed out.
My codes are:

```
 AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];        
 [manager POST:urlString parameters:parameter progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
            NSLog(@"%@",responseObject); 
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

            NSHTTPURLResponse *m=(NSHTTPURLResponse *)[task response];
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
         }];
```

i don't understand why all my request gets timed out on IPv6 only.

Comment: Do you actually have IPv6 connectivity from your phone to the server? Are you able to open the same URL in Safari for instance?

Comment: Yes, i have IPv6 connectivity, but i am unable to open the same url in safari.

Comment: Are you able to open it from your Mac?

Comment: No, on IPv6 mac also unable to open it. I have used rest client also.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: If it's always a timeout, you most certainly have an IPv6 connectivity issue between you and the server. You may try to use `traceroute6` to find out where the issue lies.